# An argument value should determine other argument keys

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I need to implement an arrayToTree function in typescript. The first argument is an array of objects to be organized in the tree, the second argument should determine which of the first arguments object keys should be used as itemId and parentId.

```
interface WithKids<T> {
    kids: T[];
}

const arrayToTree = <T>(
    array: T[],
    { itemIdKey, parentIdKey }: {
        itemIdKey: keyof T,
        parentIdKey: keyof T
    },
) => {
    if (itemIdKey === parentIdKey) {
        throw new Error(
            'itemIdKey and parentIdKey has to be different'
        );
    }

    const map: { [key: string|number]: WithKids<T> } = {};
    const roots: WithKids<T>[] = [];

    array.forEach((item) => {
        // (Type 'T[keyof T]' cannot
        // be used to index type 
        // '{[key: string]: WithKids<T>;
        // [key: number]: WithKids<T>; }'.)
        // @ts-ignore 
        map[item[itemIdKey]] = {
            ...item,
            kids: []
        }
    });

    array.forEach((item) => {
        // This condition will always return
        // 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]'
        // and 'string' have no overlap.)
        // @ts-ignore
        if (!item[parentIdKey] || item[parentIdKey] === '0') {
            // (Type 'T[keyof T]' cannot
            // be used to index type 
            // '{[key: string]: WithKids<T>;
            // [key: number]: WithKids<T>; }'.)
            // @ts-ignore 
            roots.push(map[item[itemIdKey]]);
        } else {
            // (Type 'T[keyof T]' cannot
            // be used to index type 
            // '{[key: string]: WithKids<T>;
            // [key: number]: WithKids<T>; }'.)
            // @ts-ignore 
            map[item[parentIdKey]].kids.push(item)
        }
    });

    return roots;
}
```

Is there a way to make this work without ts-ignores?

Comment: Please provide an example how do you want to call this function

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use `item[itemIdKey]` as an index for `map`, this value `item[itemIdKey]` should be either `string` or `number`.

Consider this example:

```js
interface WithKids<T> {
    kids: T[];
}

const arrayToTree = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, string | number>>(
    array: T[],
    { itemIdKey, parentIdKey }: {
        itemIdKey: keyof T,
        parentIdKey: keyof T
    },
) => {
    if (itemIdKey === parentIdKey) {
        throw new Error(
            'itemIdKey and parentIdKey has to be different'
        );
    }

    const map: { [key: string | number]: WithKids<T> } = {};
    const roots: WithKids<T>[] = [];

    array.forEach((item) => {
        map[item[itemIdKey]] = {
            ...item,
            kids: []
        }
    });

    array.forEach((item) => {
        if (!item[parentIdKey] || item[parentIdKey] === '0') { 
            roots.push(map[item[itemIdKey]]);
        } else {
            map[item[parentIdKey]].kids.push(item)
        }
    });

    return roots;
}
```

I have used a constraint : `T extends Record<PropertyKey, string | number>`.

It means that `T` is an object where all values are either `string` or `number`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0&jsx=0&pretty=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwNLACYDOAPACoB8yA3gFDJ3IDW%20BAXMiQNoC6A3NQL7VqCAPYgCYZHChQ4ATxIiSUCCgC8yUsggAPSCELIAShFFQ8RAApQRAB2hg52CHIA0yCVFABzZAB9kEABXAFsAI2gyMgAKWnppWTk2Ti5XOLpKZAwIEIBJPGc3ZFtpCHB8wuR%20Nhp6OqzIPIKXNgYXERh2NPr6EpVy5qTGds6SdKq0gEpkNQpa%20mBO6OymyrV14tKBwun5nqwbAHdAiGOAURkRKFienoByFYqXKQNN-rAnuWRMOAJkMBEyAiyDwixg0DKYDu4zqkz4dUE41E4kkITgthqyA4bSGnh8-kCoQiUC4bHQWFwhFIFH4Myo-Hh9GREmQNhEYFYaAwOGY1O4dO4fHGCXkADoYFczohMNFlo1prMqDD6GjbBwVurGp8uFw6XtbnRRUaVt0DfQmIQ2NxlXRBAi4UI6iK5OLJdLZSsFXMbVklgBCDV9SHa-wBQNbD6DXXrDR3AAMd12yB9dTZHNFtiCBBlqs1OTzqxcOodBtpEAANgQUPqDbnw%209tVxRRaCBmszLPT67fR%20A7xiowEEoCBWSJ2QQ%20PwgA)